# how to set up the environment for the v142 for Visual studio 2019 using Cmd prompt

Tags: batch-file, visual-c++, cmd, visual-studio-2019, build-tools

I am not able to build project , i am getting this error in cmd prompt(attached screenshot), please anyone can help me to resolve this issue!!
Ps: I have installed Vs2019 and also build tools
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8AZk.png)

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build>vcvarsall.bat x86_x64 -vcvars_ver=14.2

---

** Visual Studio 2019 Developer Command Prompt v16.11.13
** Copyright (c) 2021 Microsoft Corporation

---

[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x86_x64'

Comment: Post your code by copy and pasting it into a code box, (using the `{}` button). We are not going to visit an image link, and manually copy all of your code into our text editors, in order to attempt to reproduce your problem. Also we expect that you also include all of your errors and debugging information.

Comment: There is an [edit] button, for you to include all pertinent information within the question itself. Do not use the comment area to include those things.

Comment: I specifically explained to you that you need to use code boxes, and which button to use to do so. I also explained to you that you should not include an image showing your code. Please remove the image, and put everything, (code and error information), into individual code boxes. It is not our job to edit your question for you!